# Cantor Set -Containing no intervals of non-zero length -

Tags: general-topology

I am reading through https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~dnelson/storage/dnelson.cantor-set.pdf and do not understand an approach the author is explaining. In Definition 1.1, the part that I do not understand begins with "For assume by contradiction that it does not contain some interval $(a,b)$".

When he says "we have that this intersection so $C$ cannot contain $(a,b)$", what does he mean? It reads to me like he forgot a part of the sentence, "we have that this intersection...".

Can anyone explain this approach? Or what the author was meaning to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misreading. T ranscription of the relevant paragraph:

> For assume by contradiction that it does contain some interval $(a,b)$. Choose $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{3^n}<b-a$. Since the Cantor set is contained in the finite intersection of closed intervals, all of length less than $(b-a)$, we have taht this intersection and so $\mathcal{C}$ cannot contain $(a,b)$.

When he says "we have that this intersection and so $\mathcal{C}$ cannot contain $(a,b)$, he's saying that because $\mathcal{C}$ is defined as an infinite intersection of closed intervals of decreasing length, $\mathcal{C}$ lies in any finite intersection of those closed intervals. Pick intervals of sufficiently small length, and you won't be able to fit $(a,b)$ inside any of them, but $\mathcal{C}$ is still inside them, so $\mathcal{C}$ couldn't contain $(a,b)$ after all.

Comment: I thought $C$ was defined as all of the intersection of the those closed intervals. Not just any.

Comment: @Ozera Yes, and therefore $\mathcal{C}$ is a subset of any of those intervals.

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks!